# How to start Group Mention plugin development?

Tags: confluence

As an intern my task is to develop plugin for Confluence. Main goal is to be able to mention the group of people from Active Directory. I've read some tutorials from Atlassian, I have access to confluence source code but still cannot figure out how to even start.

Maybe someone knows where I can find source code of mention system? Or someone maybe can give me some useful resources?

Should I make it like a plugin macro or in some different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In confluence 5.8.8 you can find some implementation of mentioning here:

`./confluence-project/confluence-core/confluence/src/java/com/atlassian/confluence/content/render/xhtml/storage/link/user/DefaultUserMentionsExtractor.java
./confluence-project/confluence-core/confluence/src/java/com/atlassian/confluence/content/render/xhtml/storage/link/user/MentionsParser.java
./confluence-project/confluence-core/confluence/src/java/com/atlassian/confluence/content/render/xhtml/storage/link/user/UserMentionsExtractor.java`

Confluence fires events upon save page, I would start from there, get the event, parse the body page and extract mentions.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! I devideo to use annotation based listener and SO far it is going preety  good.